# How to add images to firestore storage that follow security rules and cannot be accessed publicly?

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to move my images from front-end static react folder to firestore I want those images to follow security rules, how to upload those images in a way that now one can access them unless authenticated ?
can I do this manually by adding the to firestore using firebase console then adding path to donwload ? will this link then be protected ?

```js
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";
// Create a reference with an initial file path and name
const storage = getStorage();
const pathReference = ref(storage, 'images/someImg.jpg');

// Create a reference from a Google Cloud Storage URI
const gsReference = ref(storage, 'gs://bucket/imgPath/someImg.jpg');

// Create a reference from an HTTPS URL
// Note that in the URL, characters are URL escaped!
const httpsReference = ref(storage, 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg');
```

```js
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
     match /imgPath/{allImages=**} {      
      // Read from storage !!
      allow read :  
      if request.auth != null  // Authorized
    }
  }
```

also if I get the the file on demand, will this have count as read ?

```js
getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'images/stars.jpg'))
  .then((url) => {
    // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

    // This can be downloaded directly:
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = (event) => {
      const blob = xhr.response;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();

    // Or inserted into an <img> element
    const img = document.getElementById('myimg');
    img.setAttribute('src', url);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download URLs are publicly readable and bypasses the security rules.

So if you want access to be gated by the security rules, don't call `getDownloadURL()` for the objects. In that case all access to the file will have to go through the Firebase SDKs, and are then controlled by your security rules.